# How to View DWG or DXF file python application

Tags: python, pyqt5, dxf, dwg, ezdxf

I have created a python application using pyqt5. Now I want to show DWG or DXF file in my UI without converting into another format. Is there any solution for that?

I tried library called ezdxf and still not able to show DWG or DXF in my python application which I created using pyqt5. DWG is not readable and DXF is readable but not able to show in my UI as it is.
If anyone know please help. It is standalone application so will not be able to use Py AutoCAD library as need AutoCAD to be installed in system.

Comment: A few minutes basic research should answer this. Qt is an open-source project that only supports a [limited number of common image formats](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qimagereader.html#supportedImageFormats), whereas [DWG/DXF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.dwg) is a *proprietary* image format. However, there are some open-source libraries like [FreeCAD](https://github.com/FreeCAD/FreeCAD) (which has a Python API) that might allow runtime conversion to SVG, which Qt *can* display. Otherwise, you'll have to write your own [Qt image plugin](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qimageioplugin.html) (in C++).

Answer (score 1):

`Ezdxf` includes a `drawing` add-on to render the content of DXF files into various file formats.

A backend for `PySide6` and `PyQt5` is included. The [qtviewer.py](https://github.com/mozman/ezdxf/blob/master/src/ezdxf/addons/drawing/qtviewer.py) module implements the core of a simple DXF viewer and the [cad_viewer.py](https://github.com/mozman/ezdxf/blob/master/examples/addons/drawing/cad_viewer.py) example is a skeleton to show how to use the `CADViewer` class in a `PyQt` application.

The `drawing` add-on is meant for simple 2D DXF files, don't expect all features and the quality of AutoCAD!